# SSRS 'Add Query' to dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, dataset, ssrs-2012

Using SSRS 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2, I've tried to partly base row sorting of a tablix on a calculated field:

```
=Max(Assperiod_ID)
```

The error thrown was that I couldn't have an aggregate in a calculated field, which I can see makes sense.

So with this is mind, I looked at the Add Query Field (Dataset Properties > Fields > Add > Query Field), hoping that this might allow me to aggregate instead.

The problem is, I can find no information or documentation on the use of the 'Add Query Field' option. Can someone tell me:

a.) What this is for and how it's used; 
b.) Whether it can be used to calculate aggregates?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the query you are using for generating the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Query Field**  seems to only be useful for renaming a column.

The **Calculated Field** is used to calculate a field from a field in the dataset or other calculation.

I think what you want is

```
=Max(Assperiod_ID, "DataSet1")
```

You can't use the aggregate expression in your calculated field, though. You can use this expression in place of where you would use your calculated field.

```
=IIF(FIELDS!Assperiod_ID.Value = Max(Assperiod_ID, "DataSet1"), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Another way to get what you want is to create a **#TEMP** table and add the **MAX** in the SQL:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TEMP_VALUES 
FROM BLAH_BLAH (YOUR QUERY)...

SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(Assperiod_ID) FROM #TEMP_VALUES) AS MAX_Assperiod_ID
FROM #TEMP_VALUES
```

[MSDN - Dataset Properties Dialog Box, Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220483.aspx)